# cfmailparam disposition filename does not work in outlook

Tags: email, coldfusion, outlook, coldfusion-11, cfmail

I have a very simple example for sending an image as an attachment using Coldfusion 11 cfmail tag.

```
<cfmail to="example@domain.com" from="example@domain.com" subject="Test" type="html">
<cfmailparam
file="www.example.com/image.png"
disposition="attachment; filename=""test.png""">
</cfmail>
```

I want the attachment to be called "test.png" when it is viewed in the recipients email client.

It works fine when I receive the email in Gmail, however Outlook 2013 (and Office 365 web client) retains the "image.png" attachment name.

Have I correctly made use of the "disposition" attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `disposition` is not working for you, try combining `file` and `content` instead.

```
<cfmailparam
    file="test.png"
    content="#fileRead( 'image.png' )#" >
```

[More details here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1220-coldfusion-cfmailparam-s-new-content-attribute-is-awesome.htm).

Comment: I was hoping not to read in the file first but this does work. Thank you.